# Expectation of the exponential function of Absolute Value of the Difference of Two Double parameter exponentially Distributed Random Variable

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, expected-value, exponential-distribution

Suppose, $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ be iid having double parameter Exponential Distribution with common pdf
$$f(x)= \dfrac{1}{\sigma} \exp\{ -(x-\mu)/\sigma \} I(x>\mu); \mu \in R, \sigma \in R^+ , n\ge5$$

Let,  $T=\exp(\lvert X_1 - X_3\rvert) - \exp(\lvert X_2 - X_4\rvert)$

Now I m trying to find $E[T]$. But I'm really having no clue how to deal with this!!

Comment: The hard way is to compute the expectations.  The easy way is to think about what the *iid* assumption tells you about the distributions of $|X_1-X_3|$ and $|X_2-X_4|:$ how do they differ?  Use your answer to this (very easy) question to reason about how the expectations of their exponentials differ.

Comment: Umm, I think since $X_is$ are iid , $\lvert X_1 - X_3\rvert $  and  $\lvert X_2 - X_4\rvert$ would have same distribution. So is the answer is zero?? @whuber

Comment: You also need to make sure that the expectation of each of the two terms at the end are finite for the argument to go through. I believe this requirement will place a bound on $\sigma$ (the answer is different otherwise).

Comment: Your question has $n=4$ *exactly* so why the inequality $n\ge 5$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints: You can fill in the details!

- The distribution of the differences $X_1 - X_3$ and $X_2 - X_4$ do not depend on $\mu$, so we can assume $\mu=0$. This reduces to ordinary exponential distributions.
- The distribution of the difference of two iid exponential distributions is a [Laplace distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution).
- The absolute value of a Laplace distributed random variable have an exponential distribution.
- So, now we need the expectation of the exponential of an exponentially distributed random variable, see [Distribution of the exponential of an exponentially distributed random variable?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/554034/distribution-of-the-exponential-of-an-exponentially-distributed-random-variable).  This expectation will exist, under some condition on your parameter $\sigma$. I leave it for you to find the condition! (should be simple)
- Assuming the condition from the former bullet point is fulfilled, you ask for the expectation of the difference of two iid variables. That is zero!